# Float calculation on csv in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

I want to eval a single column with

```
$(echo "1023630 / ln( 10000 /$2 )  / ( 3435 / ln( 10000 /$2 ) - 298 )" | bc -l)
```

but while reading a file its throwing an syntax error. How can I eval this?
I have tried with

```
while IFS="," read a b c d; do 
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $a $(echo "1023630 / ln( 10000 /$b )  / ( 3435 / ln( 10000 /$b ) - 298 )" | bc -l) $c $d; 
done < abcdtemp.csv 

150918021814,1421.5,1,
(sRuntime error (func=(main), adr=26): Function ln not defined.
150918021216,1421.5,1.4,
```

even with awk it's not working

```
awk -F',' -v OFS="," '{$2=$(echo "1023630/ln(10000/$2)  / (3435/ln(10000/$2)-298)" | bc -l);$3=$(echo "1023630/ln(10000/$3)  / (3435/ln(10000/$3)-298)" | bc -l);}1' file

awk -F',' -v OFS="," '{$1;$2=printf "%.1f\n","1023630/ln(10000/$2)/(3435/ln(10000/$2)-298)";$3=printf "%.1f\n","1023630/ln(10000/$2)/(3435/ln(10000/$3)-298)";}1' file
```

Any hint or help, what am I missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is a simple awk script:

```
$ cat file
3,5,7,11

$ while IFS="," read a b c d; do printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $a $(echo "1023630 / l( 10000 /$b ) / ( 3435 / l( 10000 /$b ) - 298 )" | bc -l) $c $d; done < file
3,874.94898530684189106603,7,11

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";OFMT="%.20f"} {d=log(10000/$2); print $1, 1023630 / d / (3435/d - 298), $3, $4}' file
3,874.94898530684179149830,7,11
```

It's far more efficient, robust, portable, and better in every other way than a shell loop. Differences in output value after the 12th decimal place presumably irrelevant and due to floating point arithmetic differences between the tools.

If you're not convinced, look at how long each command takes to execute when run on a file that's just 1,000 lines long,

```
$ time while IFS="," read a b c d; do printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $a $(echo "1023630 / l( 10000 /$b ) / ( 3435 / l( 10000 /$b ) - 298 )" | bc -l) $c $d; done < file_1k > /dev/null
real    0m39.066s
user    0m7.433s
sys     0m24.458s

$ time awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";OFMT="%.20f"} {d=log(10000/$2); print $1, 1023630 / d / (3435/d - 298), $3, $4}' file_1k > /dev/null
real    0m0.060s
user    0m0.031s
sys     0m0.031s
```

Comment: Thanks for logical and optimize one .

Answer (score 2):

Your `$2` is probably empty (or of some invalid value).

Also *natural logarithm* in `bc` is `l`, not `ln`.

And finally, in your `awk` example, the code is in apostrophes, so `$2` will not be evaluated at all.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what exactly "worked for you". For example, you should not use `bc` for this, and you should not enclose awk in double quotes to let $2 expand. There is a hint to the correct answer above but I would not be surprised if you did completely the wrong thing just because it gave you the output you expect in this case.

Comment: @EdMorton Actually I had used wrong variable,instead of $a,$b,$c,$d. I have used $1,$2,$3,$4 mistakenlly. Silly mistakes,when you are so furious to find out solution.It worked for me
while IFS="," read a b c d; do 
    printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $a $(echo "1023630 / l( 10000 /$b )  / ( 3435 / l( 10000 /$b ) - 298 )" | bc -l) $c $d; 
done < abcdtemp.csv

Comment: That's a very slow, complicated, error prone solution. If you had posted sample input and expected output in your question and hadn't accepted an answer within 25 mins of asking the question I'm sure someone could have shown you a better approach very quickly but I've now made up my own input and ran your script against it to get the expected output and posted an awk answer.